# For loop misbehaving in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am just trying simple for loop in the process of learning batch scripting.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (abc.txt) do echo %%a
```

my abc.txt conatins

```
word1 word2 word3
```

Now the output should be like this

```
word1
word2
word3
```

But I simply get a single line rather than three lines. Why? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Write `'type abc.txt'` instead. Besides that shouldn't be the output given `wordi` are in the same line.

Comment: This part: `"tokens=*"` means "assign **all tokens** in the input line to the `%%a` letter"... It should be `for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%a in (abc.txt) do echo %%a & echo %%b & echo %%c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `for /f` processes the text file `abc.txt` line by line on each iteration. Empty lines are skipped as also lines starting with a semicolon because `eol=;` is the default.

All other lines are processed by **FOR** according to the `tokens=` and `delims=`.

In case of `abc.txt` containing just a single line with `word1 word2 word3` the command **FOR** would split this line up into substrings (tokens) assigned to loop variables. The splitting would be done with `delims=`  (just space character) as follows:

1. `word1` is assigned to loop variable `a` as specified on **FOR** command line.
2. `word2` is assigned to next loop variable `b` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is the reason why loop variables are case-sensitive in comparison to environment variables being case-insensitive.
3. `word3` is assigned to next but one loop variable `c`.

With `tokens=` it is possible to change the substring to loop variable assignment order. For example with `tokens=2` the first substring `word1` is ignored, the second `word2` is assigned to loop variable `a` and the third `word3` is again ignored. Lines with just 1 space(s) delimited string are also ignored as not at least 1 substring could be assigned to specified (first) loop variable. The line must have at least 2 space(s) delimited strings with `tokens=2` for running the commands in the loop body.

`tokens=1*` means assign `word1` to `a` and everything after first substring to next loop variable `b` without further splitting resulting in assigning `word2 word3` to loop variable `b`.

`tokens=*` means do not split up the line at all. So `delims=`  has no effect.

Two loops are required for the task with `abc.txt` having 3 words on one line and the commands in the loop body should be executed on each word of each line:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in (abc.txt) do (
    echo Line: %%I
    for %%J in (%%I) do echo %%J
)
```

The outer loop reads the non empty lines not starting with a semicolon from text file `abc.txt` and assigns the entire line to loop variable `I`.

The inner loop without option `/F` processes this line with using the standard delimiters on using **FOR** without `/F` which are space, tab, comma, and some others.

The output of this batch file for `word1 word2 word3` in a single line in file `abc.txt` is:

```
Line: word1 word2 word3
word1
word2
word3
```

By the way: Running in a command prompt window `for /?` outputs on several display pages the help for this command. The behavior of `for /F` is indeed the most difficult to understand because of the many number of variants.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. That's lot of information. This corrected what I knew.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this:

```
@Echo off
Echo Variant 1
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in (abc.txt) do echo %%a & echo %%b & echo %%c
Echo Variant 2
For /f "tokens=*" %%a in (abc.txt) do for %%B in (%%a) Do Echo %%B
Echo Variant 3
For /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type abc.txt') do for %%B in (%%a) Do Echo %%B
```

Sample output:

```
Variant 1
word1
word2
word3
Variant 2
word1
word2
word3
Variant 3
word1
word2
word3
```

Comment: Thanks. Variant 2 helped me. Is there a way to insert newword between lines?

Comment: You could append `& Echo newword`

Answer (score -2):

Try one of these versions:

version 1 (puts the word in the file, then shows then onscreen, also what echo does):

```
         @echo off
         title text file reader/writer
         echo This version inputs text that is predefined in the source code into a .txt file.
         echo oh hey! I am text line 1>testwords.txt
         echo oh hey! I am text line 2>>testwords.txt
         echo oh hey! I am text line 3>>testwords.txt
         echo oh hey! I am text line 4>>testwords.txt
         echo Text entered! displaying below!
         type testwords.txt
         pause
         del testwords.txt
         exit
```

Version 2:

```
         @echo off
         title text file reader/writer
         echo This version displays predefined text in the source code as an "echo"
         echo oh hey! I am text! 
         pause
         exit
```

Version 3:

```
         @echo off
         title text Displayer
         echo This version displays User Entered text as an "echo" via the "set" command.

         set /p text=Enter text here:
         echo You have entered: %text%
         pause
         exit
```

Version 4:

```
         @echo off
         title text saver/displayer
         echo This version saves User Entered text as an "echo" via the "set" command, the "echo" command, and the "type" command.

         set /p text=Enter text here:
         echo You have entered: %text%>enteredtext.yourtextfile
         type enteredtext.yourtextfile
         pause
         del enteredtext.yourtextfile
         exit
```

Comment: No one of these 4 "versions" solves the problem stated in the question, that is: Using a "simple for loop" read a text file that contains one line with three words like this: `word1 word2 word3` and show each word in a separate line.